# To select the row from second table with a condition

Tags: mysql

I have input tables as below

Table a:

```
id      name    state 
12345   john    az
45678   henry   AL
11111   jack    PA
22222   brian   TL

table b :

id  queuenum    randomnum   mid
12345   100      AAAAA      aa
12345   100      BBBBB      bb
12345   100      CCCCCC     cc
12345   100      DDDDD      dd
12345   200      CCCCCC     ee
12345   200       DDDDD     ff
12345   200      EEEEE      gg
12345   200      FFFFF     hh
45678   100      a1a2a3 ii
45678   100      b1b2b3 jj
45678   200      a1a2a3 ll
45678   200      b1b2b3 mm
45678   200      E1E2E3 nn
```

In table B queuenum column will have either 100 or 200.
FirstI need to select the 'id' from table 'A' and check randomnum that same for 100 and 200 row and get the mid of corresponding 200.

I mean let's say from above 'id' '12345' has randomnum CCCCCC and DDDDD in 100 and 200. NOW I need to get either ee or ff (only one). So final output should be input table + mid column (with value of 200 having same randomnum in 100 for that id).

```
ID     name     state      mid
12345   JOHN    AZ        ee/ff (ONLY ONE)
45678   henry   AL        ll/mm (ONLY ONE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It `JOIN`s `a` to `b` twice, once to find the `randomnum` values which have `queuenum` values of 100 and then again to find the cases where the `randomnum` from the first `JOIN` have a corresponding `queuenum` of 200. The `GROUP BY` a.id then selects a random value of `mid` for output.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.state, b1.mid 
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.id = a.id AND b.queuenum = 100
JOIN b b1 ON b1.id = a.id AND b1.randomnum = b.randomnum AND b1.queuenum = 200
GROUP BY a.id
```

Output:

```
id      name    state   mid
12345   john    az      ee
45678   henry   AL      ll
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1baf75/3)

Comment: Hi John, did this help? If not, could you provide more information to help get to a solution?